# how to get only a delimiter before value .not for all

Tags: jquery, split, delimiter

I have one delimiter split function

When apply this code all the values are present. I need only the value of before delimiters like(-5,-7,89). How do I get them?

```js
function solve() {
  str1 = $('#equ').val();
  var eql = str1.split(/x/g);

  $('#test').html(eql);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter equation" value="-5x-7x-56+89x=108" class="equ" id="equ">
<input type="submit" value="solve" class="solve" id="solve" onclick="solve()">
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: Also change the type from submit to button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but you probably want to get all matches for an optional `-` plus a number which occurs before `x`. It would look like this:

```
var matches = str1.match(/-?\d+(?=x)/g);
console.log(matches); // You will get an array with [-5, -7, 89]

// For example, we can now output the values
$('#test').text(matches.join(", "));
```

Short explanation: `.match` returns an array of matches of a certain [regular expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp). `-?` matches an optional minus, `\d+` matches one or more digits and `(?=x)` checks if the next character is an `x` without including it in the match. Finally, the `g` modifier at the end of the regex makes it a global regex which will make `.match` return all parts of the string matching this regex (as opposed to returning one match plus all submatches, if any).

Comment: you are correct.i got my answer.Thanks you so much.and also thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

eql[0] will give you value of before delimiters.

```
  $('#test').html(eql[0]);
```